# Create a background-image over a background-color with different opacities for each element

Tags: css

[Here the demo](https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/BaBjqbY?editors=1100)

The code below creates a background-image over a background-color with different opacities for each element. Is there a cleaner way of achieving this?

```css
.component{
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw; 
 font-size:5em;  

 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;  
 color:black;

}
.component::before{
 content: "";

 position: absolute;
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;

 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;  
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw;

 opacity:1;
 z-index:-1;  
 background: url("https://www.pngarts.com/files/5/Los-Angeles-Free-PNG-Image.png") center 100px/500px repeat;
}


.component_background_color::after{ 
 content: "";

 position: absolute;
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;

 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;  
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw;
 
  opacity:0.3;
 z-index:-2;  
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
    <div class="component_background_color"> 
      Awesome WebPage  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Linny thanks for your feedback! effectively there was a bugg in my code, I think it works now, I let my post online for futur reader to make their review if they are interested.

Comment: So, the code now works, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten that code a bit, and then, by using `rgba()`, you can have both transparent background and image in one pseudo, and using `attr()` together with the second pseudo, display the text.

*The 4th argument in `rgba()` is the opacity level.*

Stack snippet

```css
.component {
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw; 
 font-size:5em;  

 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;  
 color:black;
}
.component::before { 
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 opacity:1;
 background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3) url("https://www.pngarts.com/files/5/Los-Angeles-Free-PNG-Image.png") center 100px/500px repeat; 
}

.component::after { 
 content: attr(data-text);
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="component" data-text="Awesome WebPage">
</div>
```

---

If you intend to use something else inside the `component`, and to avoid using negative `z-index` on the pseudo (which can cause other issue when it comes to the stacking context), use e.g. a `div` and give it `position: relative` and it will *float* on top of the pseudo.

Stack snippet

```css
.component {
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw; 
 font-size:5em;  

 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;  
 color:black;
}
.component::before { 
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 opacity:1;
 background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3) url("https://www.pngarts.com/files/5/Los-Angeles-Free-PNG-Image.png") center 100px/500px repeat; 
}

.component div { 
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div> 
    Awesome WebPage
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to alter the opacity on the background color and the image individually, you will need both pseudo, and here's how-to.

*As the `div` will become before the `::after` pseudo, markup wise, we need to give it `z-index: 1` to "float" on top. Note, this is not as bad as using a negative `z-index` on the pseudo.*

Stack snippet

```css
.component {
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width:100vw; 
 font-size:5em;  

 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;  
 color:black;
}
.component::before,
.component::after { 
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 opacity:.3;
 background: green; 
}

.component::after { 
 opacity:.7;
 background: url("https://www.pngarts.com/files/5/Los-Angeles-Free-PNG-Image.png") center 100px/500px repeat; 
}

.component div { 
 position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div> 
    Awesome WebPage
  </div>
</div>
```